# Trying to figure out a way to allow my image to move in opposite direction when colliding with object

Tags: python

A bit long, but I am not looking for a copy and paste answer. I just want to know a good way on how to approach this. Code pasted for visual preference.

In better terms. My image is colliding with another image, this object is representing the tile (floor/roof/wall/etc).

I place these tiles in different locations throughout my screen. I store these positions using rect objects and storing them into a list known as `terrain`.
So I iterate through my list and when I encounter a collision with my hero and some terrain object, stop movement.

I now realize that this is a problem. When this happens and I do collide, I can no longer move my object, it is stuck.

So how can I get my object to still move around, BUT when it has collided with some object. It is not allowed to continue to move further in that same direction.

Here are is the main piece for movement controlling:

The `moveDown` statement is the part where I try to implement it.
`floorCollusion` is a list of 5 False booleans.

```
#0 represents - no collision
#1 "       "  - top face has collided
#2 "       "  - right face has collided
#3 "       "  - bottom face has collided
#4 "       "  - left face has collided
```

I see I have binary operations. Either I move or I don't. I just can't figure another way to implement this.

You don't need to add on to the code. A basic idea on how to see this would be appreciated.

```
moveDown  = False
moveUp    = False
moveLeft  = False
moveRight = False
#when key down either move the hero or quit game
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key in (K_UP, K_w):
                moveDown = False
                moveUp = True
        playerObj['jumping'] = True #@@@@@@

    elif event.key in (K_DOWN,K_s):
       moveUp = False
       moveDown = True

            elif event.key in (K_LEFT, K_a):
                moveRight = False
                moveLeft = True

        #if the image is not facing left, display the left img
        if (playerObj['facing']) != LEFT:
        playerObj['surface'] = L_HERO_IMG
        playerObj['facing'] = LEFT

    elif event.key in (K_RIGHT, K_d):
        moveLeft = False
        moveRight = True

        #if the image is not facing right, display the right img
        if (playerObj['facing']) != RIGHT:
        playerObj['surface'] = R_HERO_IMG
        playerObj['facing'] = RIGHT

            elif event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                terminate()

    #testing hit point system
    elif event.key == K_SPACE:
        playerObj['health'] -= 3

        if playerObj['health'] <= 0:
        gameOver = True

    #when key is lifted stop movement
    elif event.type == KEYUP:
    if event.key in (K_UP, K_w):
       moveUp = False

    elif event.key in (K_DOWN, K_s):
       moveDown = False

    elif event.key in (K_LEFT,K_a):
       moveLeft = False

    elif event.key in (K_RIGHT,K_d):
       moveRight = False

#moving the hero
if not gameOver:

        if moveLeft:
    playerObj['x'] -= MOVERATE

        if moveRight:
    playerObj['x'] += MOVERATE

    #if the player pressed key up or 'w' and hero isn't jump
    #the hero will seems to have a jumping affect
        if moveUp:
    playerObj['y'] -= MOVERATE
        if moveDown:
    playerObj['y'] += MOVERATE
    for i in range(len(terrain)):
        tile = terrain[i]
        if playerObj['rect'].colliderect(tile):
           floorCollusion[2] = True
           break
        else:
           floorCollusion[2] = False
    if floorCollusion[2]:
        playerObj['x'] -= MOVERATE
```

Comment: Rather than restricting movement completely, just restrict movement in the direction of the colliding object. Say you have a function `move()`, and a set of legal directions for the player to move in. Just remove the illegal directions from the set.